# SpringBoot validate @RequestBody parameters of a simple domain class

Tags: spring-boot

I have a domain class as:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Person {
    Integer age;
    String gender;
}
```

I have below controller:

```
@RestController
class PersonController {
    @PostMapping("/person")
    public String testMethod(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return "Valid";
    }
}
```

Now I execute the API **POST /person** with below body:

```
{
    "age": "12",
    "gender": "Q"
}
```

So this successfully returns the string **Valid**

How can I add validation in SpringBoot so that:

1. age only accepts integer values.
2. gender only accepts String values - M or F

Answer (score 1):

You could use `javax.validation.*` annotations on the domain model object.

```
public class Person {

   @Min(value = 18, message = "Age should not be less than 18")
   @Max(value = 100, message = "Age should not be greater than 100")
   private int age;

   private Gender gender;
}

public enum Gender {
  M, F
}

...
@RestController
class PersonController {
    @PostMapping("/person")
    public String testMethod(@Valid @RequestBody Person person) {
        return "Valid";
    }
}
```

Note that while it was possible to resolve the "gender" with the annotations from java bean's validation package, I've proposed an alternative solution based on enums, because its even more expressive and also can answer the question.

Read [this introductory tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) about that feature

Comment: I did try this approach, but I do not get any error when I send incorrect Gender value in the payload.

Comment: Does it work for wrong integers (out of range)? What comes into an enum when you set a "wrong" gender? In general constraints on enums can also be applied although its slightly more complicated. See https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums